# Type annotation for overloads that exclude types (something vs everything else)

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to use `@overload` to communicate the different ways of calling a function, but what is easily communicated in the code with a simple `else` statement is not possible in the type annotations.  Without the "else" MyPy (correctly) complains that the overload versions mismatch (see the snippet below for example).

`error: Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types`

Did I understand correctly that there is no good solution for this problem?

eg. here is a simple example:

```python
ListOrTuple = TypeVar("ListOrTuple", List, Tuple)
# unfortunately, typing doesn't support "anything else" at the moment
# https://github.com/python/typing/issues/599#issuecomment-586007066
AnythingElse = TypeVar("AnythingElse")
# what I would like to have is something like AnythingElse= TypeVar("AnythingElse", Not[List,Tuple])

@overload
def as_list(val: ListOrTuple) -> ListOrTuple:
    ...

@overload
def as_list(val: AnythingElse) -> List[AnythingElse]:
    ...

def as_list(val):
    """Return list/tuple as is, otherwise wrap in a list

    >>> as_list("test")
    ['test']
    """
    return val if isinstance(val, (list, tuple)) else [val]
```

Answer (score 4):

*This question is old enough, but this problem arises in multiple questions. This is intended to be a duplicate target, because the question is formulated in generic and reusable way. Other questions asking about overloads with type "X or not X" can be closed as dupes of this.*

This problem (expressing type `not X` or `Any \ X`) bound to overloads is not planned for any `mypy` milestone.

First, the solution: just write both overloads as you have done, e.g. (I reduced imports and the overall complexity to simplify the example)

```py
from typing import Any, TypeVar

ListOrTuple = TypeVar("ListOrTuple", list[Any], tuple[Any, ...])
AnythingElse = TypeVar("AnythingElse")

@overload
def as_list(val: ListOrTuple) -> ListOrTuple: ...  # type: ignore[misc]
@overload
def as_list(val: AnythingElse) -> list[AnythingElse]: ...
```

... and this works as intended. The error message about overlapping signatures is more like a lint warning than a real type error [1-2]. All you need is to ignore the error line like in example above. And everything will work great. **Almost: see details below.**

This is also explained in [mypy official docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#type-checking-calls-to-overloads).

### How does it work

In short ([4]):

- When overloaded function is called, `mypy` goes over every overload and checks if there is a match. If arguments passed to function are compatible with types of overload parameters, `mypy` picks this overload and processes it further as regular function (if `TypeVar`s are involved, things are getting much more difficult - in fact `mypy` tries to substitute them and picks an overload only if this procedure succeeded). Here we consider `A` compatible to `B` if and only if `A` is a (nominal or structural, non-strict) subtype of `B`. What does it mean for us? If there are multiple matches, the first one will be used. Thus to say `(int) -> str; (float which is not int) -> float` we have to define two overloads, `(int) -> str; (float) -> float` in this order. Are you happy? I'm not, `mypy` fails to treat `int` as a `float` subtype in overloads, which is a reported bug.
- When overloaded definition is parsed and interpreted by `mypy`, it verifies its formal correctness. If arguments are not overlapping, overloads are OK. Otherwise, the more narrow are argument types, the more narrow return type should be - otherwise `mypy` complaints. Two different errors may be emitted here (numbers may differ with more signatures):

  1. `Overloaded function signature 2 will never be matched: signature 1's parameter type(s) are the same or broader`. This is a bad sign: your second overload is just completely ignored. Basically it means that you need to swap the signatures to make both work and to get another message instead:
  2. `Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types`. This is much better! Basically it says "Are you sure that it is what you want? Strictly speaking, without implementation-specific assumptions any of overloads can be picked by PEP484-compatible type checker, plus there are some edge cases!". You can safely say "yes, I mean this!" and ignore the message. But beware (see below section)!

### Why is the error message there?

Well, I cheated a bit when saying "everything will be fine" above. The main problem is that you *can* declare a variable to have wider type. If return types are not compatible, then you have actually tweaked type checker to produce some output not matching run-time behaviour. Like this:

```py
class A: pass
class B(A): pass
@overload
def maybe_ok_1(x: B) -> int: ...  # E: Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types
@overload
def maybe_ok_1(x: A) -> str: ...
def maybe_ok_1(x): return 0 if isinstance(x, B) else 'A'

# So far, so good:
reveal_type(maybe_ok_1(B()))  # N: revealed type is "builtins.int"
reveal_type(maybe_ok_1(A()))  # N: revealed type is "builtins.str"
# But this can be dangerous:
# This is `B`, and actual return is `int` - but `mypy` doesn't think so.
x: A = B()
reveal_type(maybe_ok_1(x))  # N: Revealed type is "builtins.str"  # Ooops!
```

### Examples

Finally, check out a few examples for some practical view:

```
class A: pass
class B(A): pass

# Absolutely fine, no overlaps
@overload
def ok_1(x: str) -> int: ...
@overload
def ok_1(x: int) -> str: ...
def ok_1(x): return '1' if isinstance(x, int) else 1

reveal_type(ok_1(1))
reveal_type(ok_1('1'))

# Should use `TypeVar` instead, but this is a synthetic example - forgive me:)
@overload
def ok_2(x: B) -> B: ...
@overload
def ok_2(x: A) -> A: ...
def ok_2(x): return x

reveal_type(ok_2(A()))  # N: revealed type is "__main__.A"
reveal_type(ok_2(B()))  # N: revealed type is "__main__.B"

# But try to reverse the previous example - it is much worse!
@overload
def bad_1(x: A) -> A: ...
@overload
def bad_1(x: B) -> B: ...  # E: Overloaded function signature 2 will never be matched: signature 1's parameter type(s) are the same or broader  [misc]
def bad_1(x): return x

reveal_type(bad_1(B()))  # N: Revealed type is "__main__.A"  # Oops! Though, still true
reveal_type(bad_1(A()))  # N: Revealed type is "__main__.A"

# Now let's make it completely invalid:
@overload
def bad_2(x: A) -> int: ...
@overload
def bad_2(x: B) -> str: ...  # E: Overloaded function signature 2 will never be matched: signature 1's parameter type(s) are the same or broader  [misc]
def bad_2(x): return 'B' if isinstance(x, B) else 1

reveal_type(bad_2(B()))  # N: Revealed type is "builtins.int"  # Oops! The actual return is 'B'
reveal_type(bad_2(A()))  # N: Revealed type is "buitlins.int"


# Now watch something similar to ok_2, but with incompatible returns (we may want to ignore defn line)
@overload
def maybe_ok_1(x: B) -> int: ...  # E: Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types
@overload
def maybe_ok_1(x: A) -> str: ...
def maybe_ok_1(x): return 0 if isinstance(x, B) else 'A'

# So far, so good:
reveal_type(maybe_ok_1(B()))  # N: revealed type is "builtins.int"
reveal_type(maybe_ok_1(A()))  # N: revealed type is "builtins.str"
# But this can be dangerous:
# This is `B`, and actual return is `int` - but `mypy` doesn't think so.
x: A = B()
reveal_type(maybe_ok_1(x))  # N: Revealed type is "builtins.str"  # Ooops!
```

Here's [playground link](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes&gist=b3eed20324904b995e29db0d0056f0d3) so you can tweak the code to see what can be changed.

References from `mypy` issue tracker:

1. [Just go on #12759](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12759)
2. [Just go on #13805](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/13805)
3. [Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules? But they still keep it open...](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8881)
4. [Read me! This contains a short explanation of `overload` implementation](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5119)
5. [Ordering matters!](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1270)

Answer (score 1):

Use `bound="Union[List, Tuple]"`:

```py
from typing import Any, List, Tuple, TypeVar, Union, overload


ListOrTuple = TypeVar("ListOrTuple", bound="Union[List, Tuple]")
AnythingElse = TypeVar("AnythingElse")


@overload
def as_list(val: ListOrTuple) -> ListOrTuple:
    pass


@overload
def as_list(val: AnythingElse) -> List[AnythingElse]:
    pass


def as_list(val: Any) -> Any:
    """Return list/tuple as is, otherwise wrap in a list

    >>> as_list("test")
    ['test']
    """
    return val if isinstance(val, (list, tuple)) else [val]


a = as_list(2)  # it's List[int]
b = as_list('2')  # it's List[str]
c = as_list(['2', '3'])  # it's List[str]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the work-around that I have. It works well enough for me but I don't like it at all.

```
# attempt to list all the "other" possible types
AnythingElse = TypeVar("AnythingElse", Set, Mapping, type, int, str, None, Callable, Set, Deque, ByteString)
ListOrTuple = TypeVar("ListOrTuple", List, Tuple, Sequence)


@overload
def as_list(val: ListOrTuple) -> ListOrTuple:
    ...

@overload
def as_list(val: AnythingElse) -> List[AnythingElse]:
    ...

def as_list(val):
    """Return list/tuple as is, otherwise wrap in a list

    >>> as_list("test")
    ['test']
    """
    return val if isinstance(val, (list, tuple)) else [val]
```